# Circular reference in web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, assemblies

I'm trying to resolve a circular reference in a web service. The solution builds fine and some operations are callable, but one which uses a referenced type gives a circular reference exception (below).

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type MyCoreAssembly.MyType <-------- this is the referenced type
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteStartElement(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean writePrefixed, XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write21_VRD(String n, String ns, VRD o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write21_VRD(String n, String ns, VRD o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write31_Hereditament(String n, String ns, Hereditament o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write32_HereditamentVrd(String n, String ns, HereditamentVrd o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write33_VRDResponse(String n, String ns, VRDResponse o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write43_VRDResponse(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.VRDResponseSerializer.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)  <------- this is my type
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
```

The architecture looks roughly like this:

```
Core layer <------ Data Layer <----- Logic Layer <---------- Web service
                     \/--------------------\/ <-------------------|
                                            \/--------------------|
```

Each layer is a separate assembly and the web service references all three assemblies. I've attached a debugger but it doesn't break. It looks like the internals are failing but I have no idea where as everything builds. How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: do you have a reference to Core layer from the UI where, I guess, you are calling the web services?

Comment: Why not have the web service only talk to the logic layer, and the logic layer only talks to the data layer. This will lead to some methods that just pass data from one layer to another, but may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circular reference is not in the project files, but in the objects you try to send over the webservice. One of you object has a reference to itself or an object that references to the object.

The error message tell you to look in your type: ***MyCoreAssembly.MyType***

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Instead of just a plain autoproperty, I had to convert it to a property with backing field and add a few attributes. `<NonSerialized()> _
    Private _Branch As PropertyListBase = Nothing
    <ScriptIgnore()> _
    <IgnoreDataMember()> _
    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public Property Branch() As PropertyListBase
        Get
            Return _Branch
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PropertyListBase)
            _Branch = value
        End Set
    End Property`